# VS 2005 Compile Error - Unexpected error writing metadata to file

Tags: compiler-errors, visual-studio-2005

I get the following error when trying to build/run my application:

Error 30 - Unexpected error writing metadata to file '' -- 'Not enough storage is available to complete this operation. '

I have tried the '/3GB boot.ini' solution but it caused even more problems to my computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can delete .suo (situated in the same folder with .sln file). Of course, you will lose some information about solution like last opened files etc, but this may help for some time until this file grows again.
Also, in my case trying to avoid to open a lot of files in VS at the same time, exceptionally windows forms was helpful.

Both of this steps help to make an error happen not so often but don't fix an issue itself.

Answer (score 2):

Clean Solution -> Close Visual Studio -> Delete all Files under obj\Debug\ Directory -> Start Visual Studio 2010 and Build Solution.

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled upon the same error when I renamed a project and then added a new one with a name of the first one.
And then added a reference from renamed project to the new one.
Problem was in default namespace, which they now shared.

Changing default namespace for the renamed project solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was actually using Visual Studio 2013. The error occurred in a test project that was using NMock3. To fix the problem I had to reference another project in the solution which contained an object type definition that was used as a parameter in an operation that was being mocked with NMock!

Example:

myMock.Expects.One.Method(p => p.SomeMethod(**null**)).WithAnyArguments().WillReturn("1234")

the above null value was of a specific type that was defined in another project which needed to be referenced in the test project...